# Equip the domain with the induced topology of $f$ and $g$ and let the topology on the codomain be the standard one. Is the induced topology Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f,g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=(x-1)^2$. Equip the domain with the induced topology of $f$ and $g$ and let the topology on the codomain be the standard one. Is the induced topology Hausdorff?

I have two parabola's with one shifted to the right by $1$. Also if we only had $f$ instead of $g$ inducing the topology this wouldn't be a Hausdorff space as the preimages under $f$ are of form $$f^{-1}[U]=(-b,-a) \cup(a,b)$$ (where $U$ is open in the codomain) so for every nbdh of $x$ in the domain we have that $-x$ is also in the nbhd making it impossible to be a Hausdorff space. I'm wondering does adding the preimages $g^{-1}[O]$ change this at all? I cannot find a "solid" definition for the topology induced by multiple maps. It seems that I only have the subbase $$\mathcal{A}=\{f^{-1}[O], g^{-1}[U] \mid O, U \in \tau_{std}\}$$ and the basis for the induced topology is the finite intersections of the elements of the subbase. Is it so then that the induced topology is generated by the union of sets $\bigcap (f^{-1}[O] \cap g^{-1}[U])$ for $O, U$ open in the codomain?

I'm not sure how what the preimages of $g$ look like. If I take some $(a,b) \in \tau_{std}$, then $$g^{-1}[(a,b)]=\{x \in \Bbb R \mid (x-1)^2 \in (a,b)\}$$ and from $$a<(x-1)^2<b$$ I get that $\sqrt a +1 < x < \sqrt b +1$ and $1-\sqrt b < x <1-\sqrt a$.

Comment: It's clear that indeed the topology induced by $\{f,g\}$ has all sets $\{f^{-1}[U_1] \cap g^{-1}[U_2]\mid U_1, U_2 \in \tau_{\text{std}}\}$ as a base.

Comment: But we don't even need that base here, see below.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb R$ with $x\neq y$.

Then if $f(x)=f(y)$ we have $x+y=0$ and if $g(x)=g(y)$ we have $x+y=2$, so it cannot happen that both equalities are valid.

Then if $f(x)\neq f(y)$ or WLOG $f(x)<f(y)$ we can take some $c$ with $f(x)<c<f(y)$ and consequently $x\in f^{-1}(\infty,c)$ and $y\in f^{-1}(c,\infty)$. The preimages are disjoint and open.

If $g(x)\neq g(y)$ we can do this similarly.

Proved is now that the induced topology on the domain is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

If $\tau_i$ is the induced topology, $h=f-g$ (which here is just $x \to 2x-1$) is a continuous function on $(X,\tau_i)$ which is injective so if $x_1 \neq x_2$ in the domain, let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be disjoint open neighbourhoods of $h(x_1)$ and $h(x_2)$ in $\tau_{\text{std}}$ and pull them back to get disjoint open neighbourhoods of the domain points.